# LibreOffice Writer is very laggy in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, libreoffice

I had to do a project in which involved using tables in Writer. It became extremely laggy to the point where I could no longer use it i.e stop responding. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and would appreciate any help on fixing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced LibreOffice Writer freezing or jumping around in both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows XP. This answer addresses Ubuntu 12.04 as I am abandoning Windows for security reasons (CryptoLocker). I have resolved this problem in Ubuntu. I have no reason to suspect it is related to Java or any particular version of the powerful LibreOffice or OpenOffice. I am currently using this version of LibreOffice: 3.5.7.2 / Build ID: 350m1 (Build:2). But the problem lies with the universal Linux kernel setting for swappiness and is easy to fix. Configure swappiness by editing /etc/sysctl.conf
Log into Terminal as administrator. 
Type: sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf
Add or reconfigure: vm.swappiness=100

Save.
You are done. Reboot. Your work now loads from the HDD, not memory.  There are no more conflicts resulting from file size or memory conflicts. This is a fix for serious work (such as my in-progress 1000+ page, profusely illustrated reference book).  For faster speed, use a lower number or a faster computer.  I am using an old Asus dual-core server reconfigured as a workstation. Hey, LibreOffice rocks!

Answer (score 1):

I was also experiencing extreme lags even when typing a few words. Try removing the libreoffice-gnome package and see what happens. This seems to have improved it for me.

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gnome
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't have any problems in using LibreOffice Writer in Ubuntu 13.10.

However, you could also try [WPS](http://community.wps.cn/download/) from Kingsoft.

It's a very cool office suite.